# How much does a pallet of durock 1/4" cement board weigh?

Tags: tile, cement-board

I am trying to figure out if I will need to make separate trips for my thinset mortar and cement board to keep within the safe operating limits of my vehicle's maximum load weight.

I plan on buying an entire pallet of Durock 1/4" x 3' x 5' cement board for easy loading. I suspect I will be using the majority of the pallet and returning the remainder.

How much does a pallet (60 I believe) of 1/4" Durock cement board weigh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1710 lbs, 1.9 psf for each 1/4" 3'x5' sheet. You're correct about 60 pieces per unit. 
[Durock Spec Sheet](https://hw.menardc.com/main/items/media/UNITE018/Prod_Tech_Spec/DurockSubmittalSheet.pdf)

Showing my math:

3' x 5' = 15 square feet

15 square feet x 1.9 pounds per square feet = 28.5 pounds per sheet

28.5 pounds per sheet x 60 sheets per unit = 1710 pounds

Comment: Okay, that's the same number I got. I asked because I didn't want to risk busting up my truck from misreading the datasheet. Could you expand your answer to show how you got that?

Comment: Some of the lift equipment at the big box stores does have a weight display.  To make extra sure, you could ask them while they're pulling it to load (if you're getting it from a Home Depot or Lowes type store).

Comment: @JPhi1618 I think I am going to see if I can get one of the "half-eaten" pallets instead to be safe. My truck can hole a whole pallet, but once I step in too, it will likely buckle :D

Comment: I used to load up vehicles all the time at Home Depot, and the number one thing was people overestimating their trucks capacity.  Look up the specs on your truck and keep in mind how your brakes and suspension are doing before making a final decision.